# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array. How do i print an attribute of my table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to print the query result but i get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

I'm new in PHP7, always used PHP5. I tryed different ways in order to print the result. But i still get the same error.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vivereingegneria")  OR 
DIE(mysqli_error());
     //QUERY
    $str= "SELECT `Titolo`,`Sottotitolo`,`Contenuto` FROM `Articoli` WHERE 
    `Autore`= 'Name';";

    //Execute the query
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$str);
    ($riga=mysqli_num_rows($result));

       //Count rows and print
        while($riga!=0){
    echo' <!-- ABOUT -->
     <section id="about" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
          <div class="container">
               <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                         <div class="about-info">
                              <div class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                                   <h4>'.$result['Titolo'].'</h4>
                                   <h2>'.$result['Sottotitolo'].'</h2>
                              </div>

                              <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                                   <p>'.$result['Contenuto'].'</p>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
<!--Templatetemo style per cambiare immagini!!!-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                         <div class="wow fadeInUp about-image" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                              <img src="'.$result['Cover'].'"  class="img-responsive" alt="">
                         </div>
                    </div>

               </div>
          </div>
     </section>';
     $riga--;
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452470/key-and-data-assoociative-array-help-needed-php

Comment: I think it's different, I don't want that result

Comment: you need to fetch the results - `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` - see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your while loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Your code here
}
```

inside the while loop, use `$row[<key>]` instead of `$result[<key>]`, e.g. `$row['Titolo']`

You don't need any riga counter, the while loop will terminate as soon as all the results will be fetched